# Output model parameters using vowpal wabbit

Tags: bash, text-analysis, vowpalwabbit

I plan on using vowpal wabbit to run many models with different combination of parameters (sort of like grid-search).  Each model will have a date and time associated with it.

**Question**: Is there a way to use `vw` to simply output the parameters from a given `.model` file, so I can understand what parameters were run under each `.model` file?

Comment: Try [vw-hyperopt.py](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-hyperopt.py) (more info [here](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/pull/867)), which is much more poverfull than a grid search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no.
At very beginning VW prints out a few most important parameters that it got from command line or model file. It also possible to revers engineer some parameters from model file. But in your case it's better to just store this information somewhere with associated datetime.